# dataset attributes - get/set correct camel case name

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have attribute names stored somewhere in a string and need a way to create corrected names to use with [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) api. I get the names of those in attribute style, like `data-attrib-name`. So I need to convert them to camel case and remove the `data-` in front of it.

The shortest way I found out for now is my replace below. But this feel kinda *hacky* to me. Is there a better solution / shorter way for my task?

```js
console.log(
  "data-my-test-name"
    .replace('data-', '')
    .replace(/-([a-z]?)/g, (m, g) => g.toUpperCase())
);
```

Comment: `element.dataset.myTestName = "test"`  Seen as this is built into the `dataset`property, why do you need to do this?.

Comment: Are you getting the property names and try to set them or are they already set and you are trying to get the value?

Comment: I have the name as a string and try to set them to elements. @Luca

Comment: `element.setAttribute("data-my-test-name", "thevalue")`   `console.log(element.dataset.myTestName)`  === `thevalue`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) with the attribute directly without using the `dataset`

```
var attr = "data-attrib-name";
document.getElementById("f1").setAttribute(attr, "changed");
```

Various methods:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("f1").dataset);
var attr = "data-attrib-name";

document.getElementById("f1").setAttribute(attr, "changed"); // set the attribute

console.log(document.getElementById("f1").dataset);

var datasetByAttr = document.querySelector("[" + attr + "]").dataset;
console.log(datasetByAttr);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="f1" data-set-name="set" data-attrib-name="attr" />
```

If you MUST use camelCase, you can use the `dataset` on an element you create;

```js
var attr = "data-attrib-name",
    test = document.createElement("span");

test.setAttribute(attr, 1)
var camelCase = Object.keys(test.dataset)[0];
test = null;
console.log(camelCase);
```

Comment: @eisbehr just use `setAttribute` then.

Comment: ps.. I'm fine with yours been accepted, at the end of the day it's not a race.. :)   Just happy to help,...

Comment: Thanks to you both! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, of setting and getting, via attribute & dataset.

```js
const sets = [
  {name: "data-my-test", value: "value 1"},
  {name: "data-another-test", value: "value 2"}
];


const d = document.querySelector("div");

sets.forEach(i => d.setAttribute(i.name, i.value));

console.log(d.dataset);
```

```html
<div>
  look at my data attributes, via inpector.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was a great hint!